# global change to the universal default color of plotly #444

Tags: colors, plotly-python, plotly-express

Currently, the default color of traces, borders, ticks, outlines, etc, as noted [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/), is #444. Has anyone found a way to change this default setting instead of specifying each and every single feature one would like to change?

Comment: If You want to change for a single time. I do not think there is a solution for that. But you can change it per session through templates.

Comment: @Hamzah, can you talk more about these templates?

Comment: sure, https://plotly.com/python/templates/

Comment: @Hamzah, so how do you change it "per session through templates"?

Answer (score 1):

You can start defining your template you want. Then you should add `template=template` to all plots you want to apply these settings:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# Create the template
# Put this block in the top of your file
template = go.layout.Template(
    layout=go.Layout(
        paper_bgcolor="#333333",
        plot_bgcolor="#333333"
    )
)


fig = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16], template=template)
fig.show()
```